# Посоветуйте стек для создания Android app + Server

Tags: android

У меня есть андройд приложение которое будет взаимодействовать с сервером через GCM.
Посоветуйте как постоить сервер. Какой фреймворк и сервер использовать? Желательно чтобы это все было на Java.
Пока накопал(слышал) только о WampServer и Spring или Play framework... но что проще и перспективней? Или есть еще что-то?

Comment: я тестовые серваки делаю на Node.js из-за его просто ты,хотя это скорее дело вкуса.